# How do i find all the lines/places/points where a particular function is being called in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, definition

Say I have a function named `SampleMethod`. I have called this method multiple times in my program. Is there any way I can navigate to each of the calling points in the program ?
Quite frankly, is there way to reverse the usage of `Go to definiton`. I am using `Visual Studio 2008`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the function and choose `Find All References`. This is in Visual Studio 2010 and 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on function and then select `Find All References` option.
[image]

You can also use `Shift + F12` keyboard shortcut to find all references of the function in VS 2008.